# How to get Google Analytics tracking code active in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, google-analytics

I am using Codeigniter to create a web site. The problem is I've put the tracking code from Google Analytics in my website, but no matter where I put it (header or footer), and in what section of my website, the result is the same: when I go to the GA to verify that Google is receiving the data, it says it's not.

The tracking code GA gave me:

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-65860566-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow must try to be as self-contained as possible, and thus posts needing people to visit your site are not on topic. Rather than close the question, I've edited the link out. Have you checked your browser console for JavaScript errors? Have you checked the GA code appears in your HTML source? Check also that the `analytics.js` asset appears in your network panel, and that it serves correctly with a 20x reason code.

Comment: Did you just install your GA code on your site? If so, then you just need to wait 24 hours for data to be processed. In the mean time, check in your real-time reports to see if you see your own, simultaneous hits. Feel free to PM me your site and I can check as well.

Comment: Hello my friends, thanx for alla your answer, i realy apreciate it, in fact nyuen was right i just have to whait 24 h to see te tracking code was sendig data and have been detecte, sorry for any incovenient whit my post halfer.

Answer (score 0):

You could read this to ensure you've put your code in the right place:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en